# How to copy an object when only its abstract base class is known

Tags: java, android

I have an abstract base class `MusicTime`, which has several concrete subclasses - `Quaver`, `SemiQuaver`, `Crotchet` etc. The subclass instances are contained in a `List<? extends MusicTime>` collection.

I need to be able to clone these objects, and am doing this manually by iterating through the collection and creating new instances based on the existing instance. I obviously can't instantiate an abstract class, so is there any way of calling the constructor of the same `MusicTime` constructor as each existing instance? So if it's a `Quaver` then I create a new `Quaver` object?

Comment: This is a task that's inherently tricky with class inheritance. Why are you needing to copy the objects, and can you make the objects `Cloneable` (or add a `duplicate()` method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use Prototype design pattern, with that you can add

```
abstract MusicTime clone()
```

in your MusicTime base class, and implement in all the subclasses which create its own object. 
When you iterate through list call clone.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42582/Prototype-Design-Pattern

http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-prototype

Comment: Thank you, that's a good solution to my problem. In fact, having just looked up the Prototype pattern in the GoF book the example they use is almost identical to this (graphical representation of musical stave notation)

Answer (score 3):

I see a clean and a dirty solution:

implement the `clone()` (from the Cloneable interface) method for each of the classes in the hierarchy (clean solution)

use `instanceof` operator to find out which class is the object instance of (dirty solution)

Comment: Thanks, they're both good suggestions. I definitely want to avoid the "dirty" approach, but have gone with the Prototype pattern answer as have been trying to use more patterns